# Mr. Sinha is a very wise and (an) intelligent officer

Tags: articles, ellipsis

> All the staffs of this office hold the view that Mr. Sinha is a very wise and an intelligent officer.

Is the *an* used before *intelligent officer* redundant here? If we had used just one quality (*wise* or *intelligent*) to describe Mr. Sinha, the articles used would have been **a** for *wise* and **an** in case of *intelligent* – but we have both qualities to describe Mr. Sinha, so do we need to use both articles or can a single article be used?

Comment: The second indefinite article **an** is not needed. It is also somewhat questionable given **very**, but it's not ungrammatical.  That phrase can be parsed as deletion of **officer** after **wise**.  But there is an error elsewhere.

Comment: Perhaps the writer did indeed imagine that separate articles must be used because _wise_ calls for _"a"_ and _intelligent_ calls for _"an"_, but it is not possible to divine the intent of a writer who clearly does not speak English.

Comment: Do you mean "intelligent" ("smart enough to figure things out") or "intelligence" ("a government department that figures things out about potential rivals")?

Answer (score 2):

You need to omit the 'an'.

The adjectives "very wise" and "intelligent" both apply to the same noun "officer" so they only need one article at the beginning.

Compare this to a similar sentence where there are two adjective-noun pairs in which case you would need a second article:

" ... Mr. Sinha is a very wise **man** and **an** intelligent officer."